# Joomla RSForm Pro Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu, joomla

So, I have this registration form in RSForm Pro in Joomla and there I have two drop down lists. One that fetches the US States from mySQL and one who should fetch cities/counties from that state. The problem is, I don't know how to check what state the user selected in the first drop down list. I found a way to do it manually (create a list for every state) but that isn't good enough. It should be done automatically.

Please help!

This is the piece of code that I used to populate the first dropdown list (with states). This is placed in the "items" field in RSForm Pro:

```
    //<code>
        $interestedstates = array();
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $interestedstates[] = "|Please Select[c]";

        $db->setQuery("SELECT id, state_name FROM #__osrs_states");
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
        $value = $result->id;
        $label = $result->state_name;
        $interestedstates[] = $value.'|'.$label;
        }
        $interestedstates = implode("\n", $interestedstates);

        return $interestedstates;
    //</code>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/dynamic-drop-down-change-form-example-.html) by RSForm Pro should come in handy. However, this will mean that you must preload all the values in JavaScript - I'm not sure if you want to do that.

Another option is to load the values through Ajax. Not fun, but is a better option especially when considering the fact that there are many many cities in each US state.